# Generate classes marked with the `Serializable` attribute when adding/updating a Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, wsdl, soap-client, svcutil.exe

I have to consume a certain SOAP web service in my C# application.

But I use the new project structure (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">...</Project>`) in Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.3.6). So instead of adding a "Service Reference", I can now add a "Connected Service" and select "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider". (That works fine when I enter the URI for the WSDL resource in the URI-textbox and press the "Go" button.)

However, after scaffolding, the generated code had two notable differences compared to the same service reference in an older C# project:

- the generated classes did not implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and
- the generated classes were not marked with the `Serializable` attribute.

I was able to let the scaffolding tools implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the generated classes by adding property `"enableDataBinding": true` to the `ExtendedData` section in `ConnectedService.json` and updating the service. I tried to do the same for the `Serializable` attribute (by adding property `"serializable": true` in accordance with the [command line options of `SvcUtil.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe)), but with no success. It did not seem to have any effect.

Is there some way to let the scaffolding functionality of Visual Studio also mark the generated classes as `Serializable` when adding/updating a WCF service reference in my .NET app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. It seems that the new "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider" implementation for Connected Services does not require serializable classes.

Last week I tested the new service reference and it works just fine without the `[Serializable]` attribute.